# what suits the most for creating interface?

Tags: python, user-interface

i have an application of text to speech convertor and now want to prepare an graphical interface for it.I did whole of the coding involved in python..i want to know which languages can be used for creating the GUI so that i can connect my python code to it easily..can python be used for creating the gui..
as i have no previous experience of creating the gui,would like to take ur suggestion for making the gui which is attractive not just plain thing such as we get using vb or anything else..

looking for your suggestion plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many GUI toolkits for python:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming
I would look at PyQT and wxPython first.

Comment: if i want an high end graphical interface,what should be used??

Comment: define high end. Qt is rich, can do a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a GUI can be created in Python, I recommend [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of GUI programming packages for Python in this page http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Answer (score 0):

If you're unfamiliar with Python GUI development, I recommend [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/). It's got a fairly intuitive interface, good documentation, and allows you to get things done quickly.